# Outdated Windows Sideloading Instructions for Excel Add-in

Tags: excel, office365, office-js, excel-addins

There are instructions online for [sideloading an addin](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/testing/sideload-office-add-ins-for-testing.md) into Excel for Windows.

However, I get stuck on step 4. Namely, there is no Manage My Add-in's button anywhere within the MY ADD-INS page that I can find.

Does this button still exist somewhere, or are the instructions out of date? If the button is gone, is there any other easy way of side-loading an add-in into Excel?

There are other instructions online for sideloading an add-in, but they are much more complicated and hard to follow.

Thanks for any information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page that you linked to is for sideloading in Excel on the web, not Windows. For Excel on Windows, see [Sideload Office Add-ins for testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins). BTW, its best to work with the help on the learn.microsoft.com domain. The GitHub repo that you linked to is the source files and its harder to find your way around there.